# OSM-File manipulation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, streets, geofabrik

[image]I´m having some trouble manipulating an osm-file I downloaded from geofabrik.de. For each street in the lines-layer I need to fill the missing "name" tags with the "ref" attribute listed under "other tags". Is there a way to fulfill this task in QGIS? If so can someone help me out with an explanation as I´m completely stuck. I tried to solve it with Python but handling osm files with python can be quite a task too. I provided you an image showing what I like to achieve.

Comment: You can do this with a QGIS expression. There HStore support. So you want to keep "name" if it's not empty, but if it's empty, you want to "name" with "ref" if it's available?

Comment: @etrimaille, first of all thank you for responding so fast. What you describe is exactly what I want to do. Can you go a little bit more into detail how to proceed?